# Sql Server view - Select certain column depending on the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a table 'Products' that has these columns

ProductId
OriginalPrice
SalePrice
IsOnSale (bit)

Is it possible to create a view 'ProductsView' that has these columns

ProductId
Price

where price is either OriginalPrice or SalePrice depending on the value of IsOnSale?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a case statement:

```
Create view CurrentPrice AS
SELECT ProductId
     , Price = CASE 
WHEN IsOnSale = 1 THEN SalePrice
ELSE OriginalPrice
END
```